# ORDER BY doesn't work when used with GROUP BY in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, mysql-8.0

I read that in MySQL 8, the [problem of wrong ordering when using "group by" has been resolved](https://mysqlserverteam.com/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/).
However, the following query still gives the wrong results.

```
select t.userId, ts.subjectId, 
    case 
        when ts.subjectId in (15742)  then 38 
        when ts.subjectId in (11613)  then 19 
    END as subjectWeight  
from tutor t  
    inner join tutor_subject ts on ts.userId = t.userId  and ts.subjectId in (11613,15742) 
where t.userId=207996 
group by t.userId
order by subjectWeight desc;
```

Result:

```
userId  subjectId   subjectWeight 
207996  11613       19
```

I am currently using a subquery as follows to get the correct results but that seems hacky and suboptimal when the default should work as expected.

```
select t.userId, ts.subjectId, 
    case 
        when ts.subjectId in (15742)  then 38 
        when ts.subjectId in (11613)  then 19 
    END as subjectWeight   
from tutor t 
    inner join  (
        select userId, subjectId 
        FROM tutor_subject 
        where subjectId in ( 11613,15742) 
        ORDER BY FIELD(subjectId,11613,15742) desc 
        limit 18446744073709551615 
    ) ts on ts.userId = t.userId  
where t.userId=207996 
group by t.userId
order by subjectWeight desc;
```

Result:

```
userId  subjectId   subjectWeight 
207996  15742       38
```

Comment: There is no aggregation in your query so you should not be using group by,,

Comment: Sample data would _greatly_ help your question.  You might think that your queries alone explain what you are trying to do, buy many readers would disagree.

Comment: Enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode and edit all your queries until they're executed successfully. You are not ready to use this MySQL extension yet.

Comment: @P.Salmon I need unique userId when fetching results. How do I do that without using group by?

Comment: @Akina I did that and now it expects me to group with subjectId and subjectWeight as well. If I do that, I will get multiple rows for same userId which isn't the expected result.

Comment: *now it expects me to group with subjectId and subjectWeight as well.* ... or wrap these columns with some aggregate function.

Comment: using a sub-query in the `FROM` is fine and often a much faster way of running a query than doing a normal join. This is especially true when you have a table with many rows, but you are only expecting to join with a very small sub-set. If you select out that sub-set with a `FROM` sub-query, the result will be much faster (usually)

Comment: Thank you @Akina for pushing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

With all the helpful comments (Thanks to @Akina) on the question, I solved it as follows:

```
select t.userId,
    Max(case 
        when ts.subjectId in (15742)  then 38 
        when ts.subjectId in (11613)  then 19 
    END) as subjectWeight  
from tutor t  
    inner join tutor_subject ts on ts.userId = t.userId  and ts.subjectId in (11613,15742) 
 group by t.userId
order by subjectWeight desc;
```